# What does "in an awful lot of good ways" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47601/an-awful-lot-any-negative-connotation, but I couldn't understand what he meant.

“It’s hard for me to figure out how this period stands out **in an awful lot of good ways**,” Bogle told MarketWatch.

Source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/jack-bogle-on-how-to-invest-in-a-time-of-trump-be-realistic-2017-04-13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*An awful lot* is an expression meaning *a large amount* or *a great many* (except when it is used disparagingly as in: *an awful lot of people*, meaning an unpleasant group).

The article makes clear that Bogle is not optimistic about the longer term economic prospects for the Trump presidency.

So he seems to me to be saying that he cannot see many positive aspects to the President's economic policies for the period ahead.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/an-awful-lot

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/an%20awful%20lot